# Implementing a 'Waterfall' simulation in Java

Tags: java, opengl, visualization

I would like to implement a visualisation of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gusJeslMbLc&feature=player_embedded) in Java as experience to help me understand all of the 'troubles' in creating visualisations. I have some experience in OpenGL, and a good understanding of how to handle the physics involved. However, if anybody knows of any good game engines that may help (or at least do some of the heavy lifting involved in creating a visualisation of the above) I would be grateful.

Also, I noticed that the linked video must use many separate jets in order to operate in the way it does. Is it likely that it was created using something a little lower level such as C? Is it possible to use a higher level language like Java to control such a system?

Comment: im not sure what is the problem here. do you want to create very realistic physic simulation of water fluids and make it render very realistically ? so, how real do you want to make it? that effect is very simple to achieve, so i dont see any point for using some physics engine for it, 4 lines of code will do the physics here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the video is an actual video, not a simulation. So when you say: "Is it likely that it was created using something a little lower level such as C?" I'm not sure you're getting it.
Also, the high level/low level divide tends to be exaggerated. As long as a language is Turing complete you can do any computation you want in it. The different languages just make it easier or harder to do certain things, and they do things at different speeds. The only reason people use C for intense physics (which this is not) is to improve the speed at which the simulation runs.

Comment: Yeah, the video is an actual video; I was asking about the C/Java for hardware control should one actually create software that controls hardware like in the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if you want to implement "just that", I think using a game engine is overkill. Just implement a simple particle engine on your own and you are done.

Seriously, that problem is not so difficult, any language can be used for it. The basic principle behind it is the same as behind steam organs or self player pianos. You have an input data that shows what the pattern to play is and you advance it in a given time.

Here is how I would build the basic control system. You take a black and white image. The width is exactly as wide as the number of "emitters" and the length is as long as the pattern needs to be. You read the image and start at the first line. You walk through each pixel in that line and if the pixel is black you emit a drop and if the pixel is white you don't. You then move in a given interval (maybe 25ms) to the next line and set the emitters accordingly.

The cool thing with images is that you can simply paint them in any graphic program. To get the current time to work you render the time into a image buffer in memory, then  pass that into the above code. (You even get fonts if you like...)

Comment: Brilliant answer; I was going to implement it differently but the analogy of a self-playing piano is great in explaining an alternative method. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/).

> JAVA OPEN GL GAME ENGINE